# VBA adding multiple criterias for SumIF

Tags: vba, excel

```
EndRowH = ActiveSheet.Range("H65536").End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("H1").Formula = "=SUMIFS(H3:H" & EndRowH & ", C3:C" & EndRowH & ",  "">=" & lngStart & """)"
```

I Have a criteria on the C column where it has to be greater than the lngStart Value.

The code is working till here.. But I have to add an extra criteria where the sumif needs to be done only if there is blank value in the column I

```
Dim Blank As Long
Blank = ""
ActiveSheet.Range("H1").Formula = "=SUMIFS(H3:H" & EndRowH & ", C3:C" & EndRowH & ",  "">=" & lngStart & "",I3:I" & EndRowH & ",  ""!=" & Blank & "" ")"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with complex strings you want to put as a `Formula`, you might want to use an "helper" string, in the code below I use `FormulaString`, so when you run the `Debug.Print` line, you can see if the formula string is valid.

Also, and it's only my preference, to get the `"` inside, I prefer to use `Chr(34)`.

***Code***

```
Dim FormulaString As String

FormulaString = "=SUMIFS(H3:H" & EndRowH & ", C3:C" & EndRowH & "," & Chr(34) & ">=" & lngStart & Chr(34) & ",I3:I" & EndRowH & "," & Chr(34) & "<>" & Chr(34) & ")"
Debug.Print FormulaString

ActiveSheet.Range("H1").Formula = FormulaString
```

Running this code, you will get in the immediate window the following formula:

```
=SUMIFS(H3:H10, C3:C10,">=5",I3:I10,"<>")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response :)  How do I edit this so that it would calculate only when there are blanks in the column I.

Comment: @user9459861  you're welcome :) now comes your part where you mark as "Answer", by clicking the gray check-mark on the left side of my answer, it will turn green

Comment: Dim FormulaString As String
Dim Blank As String
Blank = ""
FormulaString = "=SUMIFS(H3:H" & EndRowH & ", C3:C" & EndRowH & "," & Chr(34) & ">=" & lngStart & Chr(34) & ",I3:I" & EndRowH & "," & Chr(34) & "=" & Blank & Chr(34) & ")"
Debug.Print FormulaString
ActiveSheet.Range("I1").Formula = FormulaString

Comment: The above code worked.. Thanks for the coding tip. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd go this way

```
ActiveSheet.Range("H1").Formula = "=SUMIFS(H3:H" & EndRowH & ", C3:C" & EndRowH & ", concatenate("">=""," & lngStart & "),I3:I" & EndRowH & ", ""="")"
```